# Not found OpenCV libraries using NDK + Cygwin

Tags: c++, opencv, android-ndk, cygwin

I'm doing an application for Android using NDK. This is the code received when I compile de C++ code:

```
Compile++ thumb  : pfc_paquete_libreria_PFClib <= pfc_paquete_libreria_PFClib.cpp
In file included from jni/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4342,
             from jni/pfc_paquete_libreria_PFClib.cpp:5:
jni/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:62:33: error: ext/atomicity.h: No such file or directory
```

I found "atomicity.h" in libraries of Cygwin, but GCC compiler don't fount them.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you know where atomicity.h is, simply add the directory where it resides to the include directories using your compiler's -I switch.